# Why is youtube's "still" screen blurry?

Tags: video, youtube, web

On the youtube video at bottom of [this page](https://www.workwave.com/service/qxpress), the screencap is blurry but once you hit play, it's clear.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I'm understanding the question... but I'm not 100% sure.

(You're asking why it's blurry in the "thumbnail"/screencap BEFORE you hit play, correct?)

My guess is that YouTube's embedding is using a frame at the beginning of the video *as it's fading in*. If this is your video, the suggestion that I have for eliminating it would be to delete the video, go back to editing, and **remove the fade-in effect at the beginning of the video.**

If YouTube is grabbing a frame from the beginning of the video I'm almost positive you could fix it this way.

Hope this helps! Best of luck!